# elixir not updating values in mapset using enum.each

Tags: elixir

```elixir
map_set = MapSet.new()
Enum.each(filtered_list, fn x -> map_set = MapSet.put(MapSet.new(map_set),x)
```

Here filtered_list is a list containing string but when I am printing map_set it is returning an empty set. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to this this:

```elixir
map_set = MapSet.new()

Enum.each(filtered_list, fn x ->
  other = MapSet.put(MapSet.new(map_set), x)
end)
```

The `map_set` you assign to inside the enum is a local variable, it's not related to the `map_set` outside the enum. It may as well be called `other`, because you are discarding the variable. Elixir is an immutable language, so you need to assign the result of the enumerable to `map_set`.

If you just want to convert a list to a set, you can simply do:

```elixir
MapSet.new(filtered_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, Adam. I didn't check this MapSet.new() function.

Answer (score 4):

For each item in `filtered_list` you're creating a new MapSet in the scope of the callback function. You can't rebind `map_set` of the upper scope in the callback function (although you can read it, rebinding it just makes a new scoped variable). Instead you should use the returned value of expressions. For example

```
filtered_list = ["foo", "bar"]
map_set = MapSet.new()         # this is actually redundant 

map_set = Enum.reduce(filtered_list, map_set, fn filter, map_set ->
  MapSet.put(map_set, filter)
end)
```

This is true of `if`, `case`, `cond`, ... you use the returned value of your expression.

```
something = "foo"

if true do
  something = something <> "bar"
end

# it's still foo
something
```

if you want to rebind `something` you have to use the returned value of the `if` expression

```
something = "foo"

something =
  if true do
    something <> " bar"
  end

# is "foo bar"
something
```

By the way, you can just pass the `filtered_list` to [`MapSet.new/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/MapSet.html#new/1) and if you need any transformation you can use [`MapSet.new/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/MapSet.html#new/2)

Comment: `Enum.reduce(filtered_list, map_set, &MapSet.put(&2, &1))` :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin a bit cryptic but hellyeah :)

Comment: How is it cryptic?! According to José, captures is the best feature of _elixir_ :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin If José said that, then it is :)