# Elixir list is not updating when passed through multiple methods

Tags: list, elixir, phoenix-framework

```
def create(conn, params) do
  conn 
    |> render_json_response(bulk_convertor(params))
end

def bulk_convertor(%{"file" => %Plug.Upload{content_type: "text/csv", filename: basename, 
      path: fullpath}}) do
   list = [~w(old, new)]
   fullpath
     |> read_csv(list)
     |> form_response
end

def read_csv(path, list) do
  if path |> File.stream! |> Enum.count <= 50 do
    path
      |> File.stream!
      |> Parser.parse_stream
      |> Stream.map(fn [arg] -> %{url: arg} end)
      |> iterate_urls(list)
  else
    %{error: %{message: "Limit Exceeded"}}
  end
end

def iterate_urls(mapped_stream, list) do
  mapped_stream
    |> Enum.each(fn(url) -> url_convertor(url, list) end)
  %{response: %{message: "Request Initiated"}}
end

def url_convertor(%{url: val}, list) do
  with {:ok, %Route{} = route} <- App.create_route(%{"url" => val}) do
    route
      |> App.redirect_url
      |> add_to_list(route, list)
  end
end

def add_to_list(new_url, %{url: original_url}, list) do
  list = List.insert_at(list, -1, ~w(#{original_url}, #{new_url}))
  list
end
```

The list content is not updated whenever I try to print it somewhere using IO.inspect it shows the initial list.
I am trying to update the content of the list based on the data parsed from the csv which i am parsing using the nimble_csv library of elixir.

If I try to print the list inside

> add_to_list

only two rows are visible the header that i added initially and last row from the CSV.

Is there anything I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new `list` in `add_to_list` function, the function returns the new `list` but you ignore it. Data structures are immutable in Elixir. Check out this answer: [elixir not updating values in mapset using enum.each](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55177308/elixir-not-updating-values-in-mapset-using-enum-each/55177506#55177506)

Comment: Thanks for "Data structures are immutable in Elixir."

Answer (score -1):

As I came to know that the DS in elixir is immutable I am able to solve the above problem by making a minor change in the function below

```
def iterate_urls(mapped_stream) do
  mapped_stream
    |> Enum.flat_map(fn(url) -> url_convertor(url) end)
    |> dump_to_csv
  %{response: %{message: "Request Initiated"}}
end
```

The rest remains the same now this line

> Enum.flat_map(fn(url) -> url_convertor(url) end)

return list I wanted.

Comment: You should mark the answer given by @fhdhsni as correct instead of posting your own saying literally the same.

Comment: Yes, I did @AlekseiMatiushkin.
Can you please tell me reason for -1 here.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a knowledge base, not a tool to solve your problems. The answer should have a value for future readers; the title of the question would bring here people looking for the problem stated in the title, and the accepted answer provides all the information needed. The solution to your particular issue does not make any sense in this context, hence I nudged you to delete your answer.

Comment: I did not close it as a duplicate of the question linked by @fhdhsni because here it’s a list, and there is a map, but maybe I should.